# How to don't let file to be uploaded to repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, svnignore

Is it possible to prevent the specified file (path) from commiting to a repository?

For example, we need `somepath/database_config.php` not able to be committed.

I tried to use `svn:ignore` property, but it seems to be that it works only for working copies, not for repositories.

I've read svnbook.red-bean.com about this feature but I feel that my brain cannot really understand why the things doesn't work like I want.

Comment: `svn:ignore` should do what you need. Can you clarify what you want to prevent exactly?

Comment: When I try to set svn:ignore to the filename in repository svn says: `“Setting property on non-local target 'https://example.com/sample_path/config' needs a base revision”`

Comment: you should do your propset on a local version checked out from the repository. I don't think you can set it directly on the repos.

Answer (score 3):

FYI: `svn:ignore` will only work if the file to ignore IS NOT in the repository.

What I do when adding configuration files in a repository, is create a template file that will be kept in the repository, and then ignore the configuration file specific to each developpers.
So anyone who checkout the code would have to rename the template without the `.template` extension, and put its local configuration in it.

That way, every developper can have different configuration without affecting everybody.

ie:
Template file: **database_config.php.template**

```
$config = array(
    'host'     => 'XXXX', 
    'db'       => 'XXXX', 
    'user'     => 'XXXX', 
    'password' => 'XXXX', 
);
```

Config file: **database_config.php**

```
$config = array(
    'host'     => 'XXXX', 
    'db'       => 'XXXX', 
    'user'     => 'XXXX', 
    'password' => 'XXXX', 
);
```

You would make these svn command to add in your repository.

```
// Add the template
svn add database_config.php.template
// Ignore the config file used by the system (Should not be in repository)
svn propset svn:ignore "config.php" .
svn commit
```

Comment: @Azat, No, you do it once on the directory where you added the template file. The ignore will be effective for everybody after that. It will never show up on a `svn status`.

Comment: I try to do it on repository's directory, but svn tells me that he "needs a base revision".

Comment: I try `svn propset svn:ignore https://example.com/somepath/system/application/config/database_config.php https://example.com/somepath/system/application/config`

Comment: @Azat, Not sur you can set a property directly on the repos. You should checkout it, make your changes, and commit. You can only make changes directly to repos for a svn cp and some other commands that take the parameter `-m` for commit message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `svn lock` command to prevent a specific file or path from being altered in the repository.  So, to prevent a certain file from *ever* being committed, you could simply commit an empty file (or that contains "do not commit this file - configs should only be made on the local machine"), and then locally alter your file to contain whatever content is necessary.

After you've locked the file, you can then restrict others from modifying the lock or the file itself, but at that point if your developers are fiddling with a file that obviously is intended to be locked, I'd start smacking them around and think about removing all their write access to that repository.

More information is available in the [manual entry](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.lock.html) and [more detailed documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.locking.html).

Comment: Anyway, somebody else will have ability to _forced_ unlock this file, right?

Comment: Hey, Jeff deleted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke, so I ain't gonna undelete and migrate.  I'd ask over at meta, if you really care.

Comment: If somebody locked some file (even me), it doesn't let me commit any other changes from the working copy to the repository.

Comment: @Azat: isn't that exactly what you want though? You said "don't let file be uploaded".

Comment: Ether, the problem is it doesn't let me commit any changes at all. Even another files, which are not related to the blocked.

Comment: @Will: done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76584/what-happened-to-whats-your-best-programming-joke (we can delete these comments now)  (you may also want to upvote http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35431/provide-a-way-for-moderators-to-respond-to-the-person-who-flags-for-moderator-att/35969#35969)

Comment: @Azat: that would happen if you locked the entire repository or a directory, rather than **just the one file you want to lock**.

Comment: @Ether: no, I lock only `database_config.php`. Let's imagine that after another developer creates own working copy (runs `svn checkout`) then he changes `database_config.php` as he/she needs, then changes another file too (for example, `some_non_config_file.php`). The second change is the part of project improvement and it needs to be commited to a repository. Then developer runs `svn commit`, but svn doesn't let him/her to do it! _Only because_ svn cannot commit the changed `database_config.php` because it is locked. So, `some_non_config_file.php` became not committed too. This is a problem.

Comment: @Azat: the developer is at fault for including a locked file in his changeset. Simply omit that file from the list of files to commit and it will work.

Comment: @Ether: do you want say the developer should simply use svn:ignore for this locked file?